# Add sequential number for Fluent Forms

Tags: fluent

I have this code for the Plugin Fluent Forms for WordPress, and it should create and store a unique sequential number for each form. That code should be stored in the database and should be displayed using a Shortcode. For some reason is not working as a Snippet or Plugin.

Can someone help me? Here the code:

```
add_action('fluentform/before_insert_submission', 'fluentform_sequential_numbering', 10, 2);

function fluentform_sequential_numbering($insertData, $data, $form)

add_action( 'fluentform_saved_entry', '', 10, 2 );

  // Get the form ID.
  $form_id = $form->id;

  // Get the prefix for the sequential number.
  $prefix = get_option( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_prefix_' . $form_id );

  // Get the current sequential number for the form.
  $sequence_number = get_option( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_sequence_number_' . $form_id );

  // If the prefix has changed, reset the sequence number.
  if ( $prefix != get_option( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_prefix_' . $form_id, true ) ) {
    $sequence_number = 1;
    update_option( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_sequence_number_' . $form_id, $sequence_number );
  }

  // Increment the sequence number.
  $sequence_number++;
  update_option( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_sequence_number_' . $form_id, $sequence_number );

  // Add the sequential number to the entry.
  $insertData->data['sequential_number'] = $prefix . $sequence_number;

  // Update the entry.
  fluentform()->entry->update_entry( $insertData );

  // Insert the sequential number into the database.
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'tdb_fluentform_sequential_numbers', array(
    'form_id' => $form_id,
    'sequential_number' => $insertData->data['sequential_number'],
    'entry_id' => $insertData->id,
  ) );
}

function fluentform_sequential_numbering_shortcode( $atts ) {

  // Get the form ID from the shortcode attributes.
  $form_id = $atts['form_id'];

  // Get the sequential number for the form.
  $sequence_number = get_option( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_sequence_number_' . $form_id );

  // Return the sequential number.
  return $sequence_number;
}

add_shortcode( 'fluentform_sequential_numbering', 'fluentform_sequential_numbering_shortcode' );
```